# How to host multiple COM+ objects inside a C# application?

Tags: .net, com+

Can i host a complete COM+ object inside a C# application?
The goal is to host multiple instances of the same component to make it scalable.

Thank you

Comment: It ultimately depends on the component, but in theory yes, no problem.

Comment: Can you please point me in the right direction to find out how to do that?

Comment: Is it a UI component (An ActiveX control for example)? or something else. COM Objects instances can just be created easily (check this http://www.novicksoftware.com/TipsAndTricks/tip-csharp-create-com-object-by-progid.htm)

Comment: It is a single threaded object, no UI. If i understand it right, this type of instantiation uses the same registered com object right? So if i create multiple instances with the activator, they will still use the same registered com object which still is single threaded. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You can create as many instances as you want. If by "single threaded", you mean it's marked as Apartment (STA), there's not problem. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423077/sta-single-threaded-apartment-com-object-spawn-worker-threads

Comment: That is good news. I will create a test right away. Thank you!